# Optional parameters in titlepage

Tags: packages, positioning, titles, templates

I have a small problem with a .sty file i'm creating.

I want to have the option to add a logo in the title, which was not problem.

But if I now have a situation where I don't add a logo (either by leaving the input empty or by not heaving the command in the main file) I create a 
! Latex error: File `' not found.

The document is still created and looks fine.

Since I want to give the sty. to others I would still like to avoid the appearance of this error...

Here the code snippets i used so far:

```
%create a placeholder for a logo
\newcommand* {\@titlelogo}{}
\newcommand*{\titlelogo}[1]{\def\@titlelogo{#1}}
```

And my (unsuccessful) try of avoiding the error:

```
\ifdefined \titlelogo {\includegraphics[height=1.5cm]{\@titlelogo} }
\else \fi
```

Maybe there is an elegant solution for optional parameters in for example title pages that I'm simply not aware of.

Thanks a lot and cheers
Claudia

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/209993/how-to-customize-my-titlepage Shows a way

Comment: Remove `\newcommand*{\@titlelogo}{}` and use `\ifdefined\@titlelogo`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the built in boolean checks and create `\iftitlelogo` that is false from the beginning. When you set the logo you turn it to true. (There are more fancy ways to do boolean checks but I think this works here).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\makeatletter
\newif\iftitlelogo
\titlelogofalse% default no logo picture
\newcommand{\@titlelogo}{}
\newcommand{\titlelogo}[1]{\titlelogotrue\def\@titlelogo{#1}}
\newcommand\mytitle[1]{%
  \iftitlelogo
    \includegraphics[width=1.5cm]{\@titlelogo} #1
  \else
    #1
  \fi%
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\mytitle{Test without logo}

\titlelogo{example-image}
\mytitle{Test with logo}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot!

I meanwhile found a rather elegant workaround (to my taste), 
which just checks if the length of the String is larger 0

```
\stringlength[q]{\@titlepic}% Result is stored in \theresult

\def\mythresh{1}
\ifnum\theresult>\mythresh
\includegraphics[width=0.18\textwidth]{\@titlepic}
\else \fi
```

This requires the package:

```
\RequirePackage{stringstrings}
```